# Finding the work done, given a function.

Tags: calculus, physics

A heavy metal 2 pound bucket initially is filled with 10 pounds of paint. Immediately after it is filled, it is pulled up at a steady rate to the top of a building 30 feet high. While being pulled, the paint leaks out through a hole in the pail at a steady rate so that by the time it reaches the top, 1/5 of the paint has leaked out.

Let w(h) be the weight of the bucket at height h. First find w(h).

For this first part I got:

$$w(h) = 2+(10-{h\over15})$$

The second part asks:

Use the answer above to find the work. How many foot-pounds of work W were done pulling the bucket to the top of the building?

How do I find the work done?

Comment: Work is the integral of $Fdx$. In your case the force is given by $w$ and $dx=dh$.

Comment: @JohnDouma thanks! I got it. $W = \int_{0}^{30} 12 - {h \over 15} dh = 330$

Comment: That's what I got as well.